# Cannot access to my server without writing the client's host

Tags: apache, dns, webserver, alias

I have set up my OVH server, installing apache2, php5, mysql, phpmyadmin etc... And configured the vhosts.

The content of my VirtualHost file :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
             ServerName www.abracadabook.fr
             ServerAlias abracadabook.fr *.abracadabook.fr
             DocumentRoot /home/abracadabook/www/
             <Directory /home/abracadabook/www/>
                        Options -Indexes
                        AllowOverride All
             </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type the ip address of my server, it displays the apache default page. But after setting up my windows hosts file (I'm on windows but the server's on linux), when I try accessing abracadabook.fr the site is loaded and the root directory is right (/home/abracadabook/www) and it displays the normal index of my website. But the problem is that the site is not accessible from another client machine.
When I try to access to it from a PC which host file is not set up, nothing will load even when I access it with the ip address.

I searched in many boards and forum but never found the solution.

I hope you can help me.

Regardly,

(PS Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Edit : When I launch a node.js server on the port 8080, it's accessible via abracadabook.fr:8080 on all client machines. I really don't get the logic behind my problem. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had not the good informations.
I followed this tutorial step by step and it works well now.
[Kimsufi DNS setting Tutorial (French)](http://www.gizeek.com/2012/10/19/configurer-un-domaine-ovh-sur-un-kimsufi-avec-ubuntu-server-et-bind/)